# CodeIgniter: load view in foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have this code in my controller:

```
$array = $this->get_latest_posts(5, 0);
foreach($array as $row){
  $this->load->view('blog_page', $row);
}
```

In my model it goes like this:

```
// Some SQL query here;

$array = $query->result_array();
return $array;
```

But the view simply does not load. Where the problem may be?

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use loop in view and write the html code in loop.It Should be like :

```
$array['all_posts'] = $this->get_latest_posts(5, 0);
$this->load->view('blog_page', $array);
```

in your view file

```
<ul>

<?php     foreach($all_posts as $post) { ?>
      <li><?php echo $post->name; ?></li>//assuming the name is attribute of post.
<?php  } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = $this->get_latest_posts(5, 0);
```

then pass this array to view,

```
$this->load->view('blog_page', $array);
```

and in you view page, you can use that array.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who's still has this issue when trying to load another view as a component inside a for loop...

make sure you pass your variable wrapped inside an array before you pass it to the view.

```
$array = $this->get_latest_posts(5, 0);
$data['row'] = $row;
foreach($array as $row){
  $this->load->view('blog_page', $data);
}
```